# Rolling two dice and returning count

Tags: java, dice

I'm writing a java program to simulate rolling of two dices. For each roll, if both dice does not have the same face, i increment a counter. Until when both dice have the same face, i want to print out the counter value. Count is basically counting how many times it took to achieve the same faces on both dices.

I tried writing:

```
int count = 0;

while (true) {
    int dice1 = getRandom(1,6);
    int dice2 = getRandom(1,6);

    if (dice1 != dice2) {
        count ++;
    }
System.out.println(count);
```

The code doesn't seem to produce the correct output. I'm curious if I'm simulating it correctly based on my logic? I'm new to java and would appreciate some help on this.

The getRandom() function returns a random number between 1 and 6 since a dice can have 1 to 6 values.

```
private static int getRandom(int n1, int n2){
    int retVal = 0;

    retVal = n1 + (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (n2 - n1 + 1));

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Where do you break from your `while` loop? It looks to me like `while (getRandom(1,6) != getRandom(1,6)) count++;` should do the job.

Comment: instead of getRandom Function you can use : 1+ new Random().nextInt(6);Also you can read more about do while

Answer (score 2):

You are always printing the count. You should only print the count when the numbers are equal, as which point you should probably break out of the loop:

```
while (true) {
    int dice1 = getRandom(1,6);
    int dice2 = getRandom(1,6);

    if (dice1 != dice2) {
        count++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow there are multiple ways to achieve the same behavior. You can use `do {} while ()` too.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there!

The problem you are facing is that you are never terminating your `while loop`. You will  need something like this:

```
int count = 0;
boolean roll = true;
while (roll) {
    int dice1 = getRandom(1,6);
    int dice2 = getRandom(1,6);

    if (dice1 != dice2) {
        count ++;
    } else {
       roll = false;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

I added a `boolean` which states if a dice should be rolled. Once the two dices have an equal value, `roll` is set to false and the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dice
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        Scanner myInput=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Tell me how many rolls of dice you would like to see");
        int numRolls=myInput.nextInt();

        //create array based on rolls
        int [] diceArray=new int[13];
        int diceRoll1;
        int diceRoll2;
        for(int index=0;index < numRolls;index++)
        {
            //diceArray[index]=(int)(Math.random()*11)+2;
            diceRoll1=(int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            diceRoll2=(int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            diceArray[diceRoll1]++;
        }
        for(int index=2;index<diceArray.length;index++)
        {
            //System.out.println(diceArray[index]);
            System.out.println(index + " " + diceArray[diceRoll1]);
        }
}

}
```